# disable mouse wheel on number inputs

Tags: angularjs

I am triyng to disable mouse wheel on number inputs because users can make the mistake of scrolling down just after updating the value.

I found this link :
https://gist.github.com/pererinha/aaef044b021bbf7372e5

So i added the directive in my app :

```
.directive('ignoreMouseWheel', function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.bind('mousewheel', function (event) {
                var scrollAmount = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1 + $document.scrollTop();
                event.preventDefault();
                $document.scrollTop(scrollAmount);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

It works with Chrome but on firefox, when i focus in a field, if i scroll, number is updated.

Can you help me to disable it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WebKit desktop browsers add little up down arrows to number inputs called spinners. You can insert css code

```
turn them off visually like this:
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

Note that some other functionality still exists, like being able to increment the number via the scroll wheel on a mouse.
see : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/turn-off-number-input-spinners/